# Async / Await is not working on secondary post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, request, http-post

I have a sequence of async / await in my google cloud function. The problem, is when i added up an new post request, the whole sequence stops at that point, by moving to catch block, its just an post request, but i dont know why its stopping there.

Her is the code :

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const request = require('request');
const rp = require('request-promise');

module.exports = async function(req, res) {

try{

const phone = String(req.body.phone).replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
const payment_id = String(req.body.razorpay_payment_id);
const amount = parseInt(req.body.amount);
const couponCodeName = (req.body.couponCodeName);
const couponUsage = (req.body.couponUsage);
const finalAddress = (req.body.finalAddress);
const quantity = (req.body.quantity);
const orderNumber = (req.body.orderNumber);
const orderStatus = (req.body.orderStatus);

const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri:'https://....',
    body: {
        amount
    },
    json: true
};

const orderConfirmationSms = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://smsprovider.....',
    body: {
        quantity,
        amount
    },
    json: true
};

       await admin.auth().getUser(phone);

       const orderResponse = await rp(options)

       await admin.database().ref('trans/'+ phone)
                .push({ pay_id: orderResponse.id });

        await admin.database().ref('ord/'+ phone)
                .push({ payment_id });   

        await rp(orderConfirmationSms)  

        await admin.database().ref('addr/'+phone)
            .push({address: finalAddress});

        await admin.database().ref('ds/'+phone+'/'+orderNumber)
                .set({ orderStatus: orderStatus });       

        if(couponCodeName) {       
            await admin.database().ref(`couponCodes/${couponCodeName}`)
             .update({couponUsage: couponUsage + 1 });
          }

        res.status(200).send({ success:true });
    }
    catch(error) {
       res.status(422).send({error});
    }
};
```

the problem is with the 5th await, the whole sequence stops there. I dont know whats wrong, as i couldnt see any error. Please help me to resolve this.

**Update:**

The issues , solved as , there was an typo. ! Thanks for the time guys

Comment: Is there any error in the catch block??

Comment: I am just getting request failed as error in catch block, i couldn't see much more

Comment: I believe it's not just request failed  message have some more info can be there

Comment: there was an typo, the issue was solved @iambatman thanks buddy !